# Alter a MySQL table by providing the new schema

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to alter the schema of a mysql table by simply providing the new schema and having the database figure out how to migrate?  For example, let's say I have a table with two columns: id, name.  I want to modify this table by adding a new column: title.  I know that I can issue the command ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN title.  Is there a way I can just provide the complete schema and have mysql figure out that it needs to add a title column?

I hope that makes sense what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can't do this by itself, but I found a [blog](http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=98) that says MySQL Workbench can do it.

Answer (score 0):

No - It cannot do that just giving your database a new schema. It would have to go about and second guess what to do with the data. (Also what happens to triggers, stored procedures ...)

You have a couple of choices

1. Modify each table and decide what needs to be done
2. Export the data, create a new database and then figure out how to import it into the new regime.

Comment: How much "second guessing" would be required? Just match up the columns in the old and new schemas, and perform an `alter table` with appropriate `add column`, `modify column`, and `drop column` parameters. The only thing it can't figure out automatically is if you want to rename a column.

Comment: ... Consider store procedures, triggers, the use of the data and how the change of one table will effect another table. Would you like the best asset that you have not to consider some of the implications that dropping a column (for example) will effect referential integrity).